# Django: calling parent variable on django models

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-models

I have a model Parent having a foreign key to Child. What i am trying to achieve is something like below. Making the ForeignKey object reference a value from Parent class. The implementation I am trying to achieve is as below. I am using **Django 1.8** with **Python 2.7**

```
class Child(models.Model):
    name = models.Charfield(max_length=20)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.name = Parent.name

class Parent(models.Model):
    parent_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    children = models.ForeignKey(Child)
```

Comment: I think your model design is wrong, here one child has multiple parents. You have to give foreignkey field in child table.

Comment: I should have a foreign key pointing to from Child to Parent over and above the Parent having a foreign key to Child?

Comment: So what is your issue now?

Comment: My issue is just figuring out how to reference the Parent name on the child instance.

Comment: Is this your whole model? or can you show me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From this model fields, your child has multiple parents and you can take the first parent name as;

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.name = self.parent_set.all()[0].parent_name
    super(Child, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```